# Javascript reading json file deprecated, updating code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am reading a json file with javascript using this code:

```
var json = $.getJSON({'url': "data.json", 'async': false}); 
    json = JSON.parse(json.responseText);  
    console.log(json);
```

The browser keeps telling me:

Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user’s experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

So, I'm guessing I shouldn't be doing this in this way?

What is the better way to do this, javascript or jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the 'async' to false is not recommended. This will block your next statement from execution.

```
$.getJSON("data.json", function(response){
    console.log(JSON.parse(response))
})
```

If you still want your code to be synchronous, use $.ajax with async: false. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/